# I get null when I want to pass as a parameter bytes[] array using URL ACTION in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a hyperlink that sends a pdf file in bytes by parameter by Url action the controller displays the pdf but for some reason the parameter in the controller is always null. I want to know what can I do?

View

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Files)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("GetPDF", "Home", new { item.File })">Click Here</a>
}
```

I tried doing like this too adding (`array = item.File`)

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Files)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("GetPDF", "Home", new { array = item.File })">Click Here</a>
}
```

Controller

```
public FileContentResult GetPDF(byte[] array)
{
    return File(array, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: In the browser, what is the resulting URL in the `href`?  Taking a step back... *Why* would you want to do this?  It looks like you're sending the entire contents of the file to the client, for the purpose of having the client send it back to the server.  That's a lot of network activity to accomplish nothing.  Why can't you use some kind of *identifier* for the file, rather than the entirety of the file itself?

Comment: @David can't see why the href is null and generates an error, but I have a loop that brings all the documents from the database and also contains the pdf file in bytes, name , etc. What do you recommend from html view to click and display the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a second answer for edge cases where a user might indeed want to send an entire file in only the first page...

You don't need the `GetPDF` controller action at all.  Just take a look at what that action does in the first place:

```
public FileContentResult GetPDF(byte[] array)
{
    return File(array, "application/pdf");
}
```

It's just returning the exact same data that the client sent it.  If the client already has that data, there's no need for the client to send that data back to the server just to get another copy of it.

Convert the bytes to a Base-64 string and use that string in a `data:` URL on the link.  For example:

```
<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(item.File))">Click Here</a>
```

Keep in mind that this sends *the entire file* to the browser when this page loads.  Which means:

1. If you have multiple files on the page, the user has to download *all of them* in order for the page to fully display.
2. If you're presenting multiple files with the intent that the user selects only some of them (or potentially *none* of them), the user still has to download *all of them* in order to make (or not make) that selection.

Basically, by this method the user *already downloads the entire file* just to view the page, whether they want to actually download/save the file or not.  Because the entire file is embedded in the content of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in the first place.

Take a step back and consider what you're trying to do here...

1. Put *the entire file* in a link and send it to the client.
2. The client clicks the link and sends *the entire file* to the server.
3. The server responds with *the entire file*.

Additionally... You want to put the entire contents of *every file* on the first page, only for the user to select only a subset of that?

Why would you want to transfer the file across the network ***three times***, in addition to transferring ***many files*** in the first page that the user doesn't even need or want?

---

In a comment on the question above you indicate:

> I have a loop that brings all the documents from the database

Then presumably you have some **unique identifier** for each record in that database table?  Use *that* on the link instead:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Files)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("GetPDF", "Home", new { id = item.ID })">Click Here</a>
}
```

This only sends the *identifier* for the file to the client.  Then when the user clicks on the link, they are providing that *identifier* to the server:

```
public FileContentResult GetPDF(int id)
{
    // fetch the file from the database here, then return it below...

    return File(array, "application/pdf");
}
```

The server-side code would use that identifier to fetch the file data from the database and return it to the client.

---

A couple asides...

1. It's generally not a great idea to store *files* in a database.  File systems are more suited for that operation.  The database can store the *path* to the file on the file system.
2. If you *must* store the file data itself in the database (not unheard-of, just not ideal) then when you're populating the links on the first page make sure you don't *select* all of that file data from the database, since you don't need it at that time.

Comment: Yes, I have to list document names on the screen and I want to give the user the option to click and convert the bytes to pdf because I don't have a path or pdf file  in the database I only have bytes.

I also have an identifier, but I have to send the ID, then call the database to get the file and get the bytes and then convert it. I wanted to know if, having the bytes directly, I can somehow quickly convert to pdf.

Comment: @Michaelweston: If you have the bytes of the file then you can return that in the `return File()` operation in your `GetPDF` action.  (There should be an overload of `File()` in this case which accepts a byte array, or at worse a stream which can be created from a byte array.)  So it's not clear what the problem is at this point.  When you attempt what this answer proposes, what specifically doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Previously I was doing what you propose to send an ID, but for that I also have to call my database again to get the bytes and then convert the bytes to pdf, so for me that was an extra step, that's why I wanted to know if I already have the bytes when I do the for each directly send those bytes in my controller and download it because it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What doesn't work for me is when I send the Bytes from URL Action it appears null in my controller.

Comment: @Michaelweston: What you had previously was the correct approach.  What you're trying to do now is wasteful.  For example, how many files are listed on the page?  How many will the user select to download?  If you list 10 files on the page, and the user only wants 1 of them, then your approach is to: (1) send the user *all 10 files*, (2) the user *sends back* 1 file, (3) you send the user that same file *again*.  ***Why?***  There's no reason to do this.  You're trying to save a few bytes of source code at the expense of ***tons*** of network traffic and a ***much*** slower UX.

Comment: @Michaelweston: *"What doesn't work for me is when I send the Bytes from URL Action it appears null in my controller."* - This answer proposes to **not** do that.  So to say that's what doesn't work when you implement this answer is to indicate that you've entirely misunderstood this answer.  Don't put the entire file data on the URL.  Because it makes no sense to do that.  Put **an identifier** for the file on the URL, then use that identifier in the second controller action to fetch the file data from the data source and return that.

Comment: I have a list of documents for now I need each document to have a link or button where the user can click and view it, in that case as I have bytes of the document I want to know how to convert it to PDF. I don't need 10 or 20, just 1 a time.

Comment: @DavidI used to do it with an identifier, so do you recommend doing it that way? instead of directly sending the bytes to the controller?

Comment: @Michaelweston: Yes.  I recommend *not* forcing the client to download all of the files, then upload one of the files back to the server just to download it again.  That's entirely wasteful.  *If you do* want to send the files to the client on the first page, I've added a second answer to cover that.  It's a rare edge case though and unlikely to be what you want to do here.  In most cases, especially when listing multiple files, you wouldn't want to *force* the user to download *all* of the files right away, but instead let them select which one(s) they want to download.